# match a prefix in a url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been working on validating a part of the url to check if a certain prefix occurs only at the start of the url.

For some reason, with the code below, it throws exceptions saying "illegal token" any help would be appreciated

Basically, i am getting a certain prefix in a url for eg /test/ and seeing if it occurs in the beginning of teh url. and replace the prefix in a url with ""

```
   var urlPrefix = "/test/";
   var Rexp = new RegExp('^' + urlPrefix);
    var hasPrefix = Rexp.test(url);
    if(hasPrefix) {
        url = url.replace(Rexp, "");
    }
```

It keeps complainng when i try to create a regexp constructor complaining of an illegal token.  any pointers

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using? I initially wondered whether you need to escape those `/` characters (I'm assuming they're meant to be literal slashes?), but no error in Google Chrome using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/2YxLj/3/

Comment: For the record, you can also get rid of all the `hasPrefix` stuff, it's redundant. Just do the `url.replace(...)`—if there's no match, nothing will be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code just a little bit (added a test url, and logged the result at the end) and all is working fine for me:

```
var url = '/test/hello-there.html';

var urlPrefix = "/test/";

var pattern = new RegExp('^' + urlPrefix);
var hasPrefix = pattern.test(url);
if(hasPrefix) {
    url = url.replace(pattern, "");
}

console.log(url); // says 'hello-there.html'
```

[jsfiddle example (open console to see results)](http://jsfiddle.net/q844g/)

Comment: Thanks all,  there were some illegal chracters at that line while copy/paste . thanks i sorted that out. thanks for all teh help.